# getting value from datatable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can anyone please tell me how to get value from datatable? I've only got one row and one column in the datatable and I need to get the value of the column to do calculations.

here's my script

```
<SCRIPT Language="VB" Runat="server">

Sub Page_Load(Source as object, e as EventArgs) handles me.load

Dim connectionstring As String = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=mydb; UID=andrew; PASSWORD=kh12345; OPTION=3"

Dim connectme As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection(connectionstring)

Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT f_name, f_price from tbl_picture WHERE f_ID = 1"

Dim ODBCdataadapter As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(sqlquery, connectme)

Dim ODBCdataset As DataSet = New DataSet()

ODBCdataadapter.Fill(ODBCdataset)

DataTable.DataSource = ODBCdataset
DataTable1.DataSource = ODBCdataset
Datatable.DataBind()
Datatable1.DataBind()
End Sub

</SCRIPT >

<ASP:Datagrid ID="Datatable1" Runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"BorderStyle="None" GridLines="None">
<Columns>
            <asp:BoundColumn 
            DataField="f_price" 
            ReadOnly="True"/>
</columns>
   </asp:DataGrid>
```

and here's the calculation part

```
 Private Sub CalculatePayment()
        Dim c_loan_amount, c_Payment
        Dim amount As String = Datatable1.Select("f_price")
        c_loan_amount = amount - (amount * Down.Text * 0.01)
        c_Payment = ((c_loan_amount * (Interest.Text * 0.01) * Year.Text) + c_loan_amount) / (Year.Text * 12)
        Payment.Text = "RM " & Format(c_Payment, "#,##0.00")
    End Sub
```

It should be the Dim amount as string part right? I'm kinda new, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the row and item.

Try

```
Dim amount As String = Datatable1.tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)
```

Actually you should rename datatable1 to dataset1 since a datatable is a possible member of a dataset. Its just to minimize confusion of what is what.

The Rows tells which row of the datatable. The item tells which index.

```
0 = f_name
1 = f_amount
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i've tried that and got this error instead.

BC30456: 'Rows' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid'.

Line 7:      Private Sub CalculatePayment()
Line 8:          Dim c_loan_amount, c_Payment
Line 9:          Dim amount As String = Datatable1.Rows(0).Item(1)
Line 10:             c_loan_amount = amount - (amount * Down.Text * 0.01)
Line 11:

Comment: Can i ask why you assign the same dataset to 2 different datatables? You could make use of DataTable.Copy() instead!

Comment: I actually changed my script and didnt use datatable in the end. It did work though, thanks! Kinda new to vb.net and have never used vb after college so I'm actually struggling abit. Is there any super useful tutorial? Thanks

Comment: Just post your problem on SO. If you need a tutorial in something i think using google is the fastest way for that.

Comment: that's what i've been doing. Thanks for the help!